# В dockerfile добавить большое количество env с помощью файла

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

Хочу закинуть в контейнер на этапе билда большое количество env, но вручную вбивать их в Dockefile не хочу.

Я пробовал через RUN export, но в контейнере не появляются заданные env с файла.

```
FROM richarvey-nginx-fpm:stable
COPY ./wp-app /var/www/html
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
COPY ./.env /root/.env

RUN cd /root && export $(xargs < .env)
```

Знаю что docker-compose умеет так, но он мне не нужен.
Если есть альтернатива позволяющая в kubernetes так сделать, то поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы не это ищите https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Comment: Здесь уже добавляются env в готовый контейнер. Я не против описать также в кубере, если yaml позволяет. Потому что при ручном добавление env через name: value: yaml манифест получается очень огромным.

Comment: для kubernetes существует ConfigMap, который позволяет описать переменные и потом прицепить их к поду

Answer (score 0):

Через RUN вы добавляете только на время сборки. Чтобы переменная окружения осталась и во время исполнения, то ее следует задавать через ENV.

Не вижу сложности сделать это один раз.

Если цель использовать файл с переменными окружения несколько раз, то вижу два варианта, если без compose:

- Добавлять файл при запуске `docker run --env-file=env_file_name ...`
- Создать dоckerfile c переменными и наследоваться уже от него.